# Problems with materialize call to js process

Tags: php, jquery, materialize

I'm working with one web app using Materialize, everything work fine till add search field. There are no error but button do nothing. In the same row, there are two buttons, first one work.

**usuario.php**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col s6 left">
        Buscar:
        <div class="input-field inline">
            <input id="fCriterio" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="fCriterio">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-floating btn-small blue" onclick="buscarCrit()">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col s2 right">
        <button class="btn modal-trigger blue" data-target="idModal1">
            Nuevo
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And js (**user-functions.js**) included is just a test:

```
function buscarCrit(){
    M.toast({html: "Buscando", classes:'green'});   
}
```

I copy another button who is working and doesn't work, no error, no nothing.

Comment: I would look to verify the ID of your modal, you are stating the ID is `idModal1`. Also I would verify that modal trigger is expecting `data-target` to always be ID and not expect the `#`.

Comment: That button work fine, first one its the problem, thank's imvain2

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the error, it was very simple but I did not see it, the call to the function has to have parentheses at the end of its name.

`

```
   <a class="btn-floating btn-small green" data-toggle="modal" onclick="buscarCrit()">
         <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   </a>
</td>`
```

Thank's @imvain2 and @Zugor for your time and help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a click event than inline `onclick`. Declare a click event listener for that button and call `buscarCrit` in there.

**Example:**

```js
function buscarCrit(){
    alert('Hello World!')
    M.toast({html: "Buscando", classes:'green'});   
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById('btn-foo').addEventListener('click', buscarCrit);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    
    <div class="col s6 left">
        
        Buscar:
        <div class="input-field inline">
            <input id="fCriterio" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="fCriterio">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button id="btn-foo" class="btn-floating btn-small blue">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
        
    </div>

    <div class="col s2 right">
        <button class="btn modal-trigger blue" data-target="idModal1">
            Nuevo
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try, but not function call, just try to open file "http://localhost/buscarCrit" thank's Zugor

Comment: It's the same, look for "http://localhost/buscarCrit", no message or toast. :(

Comment: That's is error message 'TypeError: can't access property "addEventListener", document.getElementById(...) is null'

Comment: did u put the id attribute in button?

Comment: Yes, attribute is was writen id="btn-foo".

Comment: Well after many tests, it occurred to me to call the function from another button that call hi's function, I changed the name and the same thing happened. In the end I realized that although I did not pass any data, I had to put the parentheses !!!. Thanks for the collaboration colleagues and I am still learning.
This it is `<a class="btn-floating btn-small red accent-3" data-toggle="modal" 
                        onclick="prueba()">'